# how to observe property changes of Backendless database ? - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, backendless

I have this code in Swift 3 to get backendless user so I can get his/her properties:

```
            let whereClause = "objectId = '\(userId)'"

            let query = BackendlessDataQuery()
            query.whereClause = whereClause

            let data = Backendless.sharedInstance().persistenceService.of(BackendlessUser.ofClass())

            data?.find(query, response: { (result) in

                let user = result?.data.first as! BackendlessUser

                myLabel.text = user.getProperty("firstName") as! String

          })
```

The code is working fine but my question is how to observe the property changes ? is there a way if the value of property `firstName` changed I can update my label automatically ?

Answer (score 0):

The use-case you describe is not really as simple as it may seem, but it's definitely possible.

You can capture any changes in Users table by creating an afterUpdate [event handler](https://backendless.com/documentation/business-logic/java/bl_data_service_handler.htm). From there you could publish a message to [some dedicated channel in messaging service](https://backendless.com/documentation/messaging/rest/messaging_message_publishing.htm).

At the same time, your application should be [subscribed to this same channel](https://backendless.com/documentation/messaging/rest/messaging_message_subscription.htm). This way you could update your UI when the appropriate message is received.